# How can I fire a zoom out event in browser resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, window-resize

I  am using `leafletjs` for my test app. I need to fire the zoomout event when the browser is resized.

Here is my browser resize code:

```
(function(){
    $(window).on("resize", resize); 
    function resize() {
        "use strict";

        if($(window).width() <= 765){
            mapOptions.zoom = 5;
            console.log(mapOptions.zoom);
        }
    }
})();
```

This code if to show the map:

```
L.TopoJSON = L.GeoJSON.extend({
    addData: function(jsonData) {    
        if (jsonData.type === "Topology") {
            for (key in jsonData.objects) {
                geojson = topojson.feature(jsonData, jsonData.objects[key]);
                L.GeoJSON.prototype.addData.call(this, geojson);
            }
        } else {
            L.GeoJSON.prototype.addData.call(this, jsonData);
        }
    }  
});

var tiles = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png");
var latlng = new L.LatLng(28.40, 84.15);
mapOptions={
    dragging: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    scrollWheelZoom: false,
    doubleClickZoom: false,
    touchZoom: false,
    attributionControl: false,
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 7,
    layers: [tiles]
};
console.log(mapOptions.zoom + 'first');

map = L.map('map-nepal', mapOptions);
map.invalidateSize();

var topoLayer = new L.TopoJSON();
$.getJSON('js/map/districts.topo.json').done(addTopoData);
```

What I have done is create a global variable called `mapOptions`. First the map is initialized with `mapOptions.zoom = 7` and when the browser is resized, then I have changed the value of the `mapOptions.zoom` to `6`. The value has changed but there is no effect in zoom of the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the zoom level of the map, try `setZoom()` function instead of `mapOptions.zoom` when you want to change the zoom level of map. So, in your case, use this

```
map.setZoom(6);
```

Hope it'd work.